# How can I create a function which treats a passed parameter as a literal?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, pass-by-value

I am sure that this has been asked and answered before, but I can't seem to find the right terminology to find an answer. I need to dynamically create a series of functions for later use which use certain values defined by parameters upon creation. For example:

```js
var i = "bar";

var addBar = function(x) {
    // needs to always return x + " " + "bar"
  return x + " " + i;
}

i = "baz";

var addBaz = function(x) {
    // needs to always return x + " " + "baz"
  return x + " " + i;
}

alert(addBar("foo")); // returns "foo baz" because i = "baz"
```

Is there a way I can pass `i` to these functions so that the original value is used, and not the reference to the variable? Thank you!

Comment: I can think of three solutions: 1. Use two separate variables (`const`, actually): `i` and, say, `j`. 2) Just write the values inline, e.g. `return 'foo ' + i;` 3) Use [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying).

Comment: Thanks! The first two options aren't possible in my actual situation, but it sounds like currying — if I understand it correctly — is just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to do something that stores the variable. Making a function that returns a function is one way to do it.

```js
var i = "bar";

var addBar = (function (i) { 
  return function(x) {
    return x + " " + i;
  }
}(i));

i = "baz";

var addBaz = (function (i) { 
  return function(x) {
    return x + " " + i;
  }
}(i));

console.log(addBar("foo")); 
console.log(addBaz("foo"));
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this qualify as "currying"?